# Starch Amylase Experiment using Iodine

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

The starch and iodide test is to detect amylose, a polysaccharide. We add an iodide solution to a sample and observe a color change with the starch; it turns dark blue. I am doing a bio/chem experiment on how pH changes Amylase digestion of Starch.

My recent trials have all failed, as the amylase starch solution is not showing any blue colour. Since I think its because that the amylase and starch solution is too concentrated and thats why they are digesting quickly, I am wondering, what percent should my amylase and starch solution be?